# create setup file and let user choose where to save database

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, winforms

with very short words,
i have created a project which contains database using sql server; and of course i want the database to be separated or in some place away from drive C so i want to let the user choose where to save his database when he install program to be able to move it if necessary and not to lose data all the time because employees are not well-trained using computers
or if possible make whole program portable
can somebody help me or send me link with clear explanation because i couldn't find something helpful
thnx in advance

Answer (score 0):

It's very easy to create a database dynamically using `SQL Server Compact Edition (SQL CE)` which is a compact relational database that is very easy to configure and deploy from your application dynamically. It sounds like a viable solution for the environment you describe. Rather than recycling code I found some good beginner resources for you:

1. [Getting Started with SQL Server Compact Edition](http://arcanecode.com/2007/01/22/getting-started-with-sql-server-compact-edition/)
2. [Create a SQL Server Compact Edition Database](http://arcanecode.com/2007/01/25/create-a-sql-server-compact-edition-database-with-c/)
3. [Create a Table in SQL Server Compact Edition](http://arcanecode.com/2007/01/26/create-a-table-in-sql-server-compact-edition-with-c/)